# How to append specific Youtube Video ID from a JSON call into an IFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-maps-api-3, youtube-api

I'm creating a neighbordhood map for a project of bars and restaurants in Louisville.  I need to have the iFrame populate a relevant video to each location when the Marker is clicked.  I'm using the Youtube Data API to retrieve the videoId based on the geo location, and in my console that information retrieval is going correctly.  What I'm having issues with is 'pushing' the video ID into the IFrame in the index.html file.  I've tried several different ways, from appending just the url string with the concatenated url, to attempting to append the entire IFrame object into a div, but nothing is working.  The IFrame is there and works with a static video URL, but I'm unable so far to get dynamic updates based on the user activity (clicking a Marker).

Here is the Fiddle (the map doesn't show up on JSFiddle, but does in Chrome btw).  Here is a snippet of the offending piece of my javascript file.

http://jsfiddle.net/smith1jason/mp5czfj9/

```
                var ytRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("failed to get Youtube resources");
            }, 10000);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                var yt_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=' + this.title + '+louisville&maxResults=1&callback=?&key=AIzaSyActmR_LWyXc0Y9CxHucYh-C73C09Om318';
                //make some room for youtube ajax call and supporting code here.
                $.getJSON(yt_url, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var title = response.items[0].id.videoId;
                    var playerUrl = 'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + title + '"';
                    $player.append(playerUrl);
                    //var contentString = '<iframe width="320" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+title+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                    //var ytWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    //content: contentString
                    //})
                    //ytWindow.open(map, marker);

                }
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  I've searched quite a bit of youtube and google map api questions here on Stack Overflow and received a lot of help not totally related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

It's in the concatenation of the url in the contentString as shown in the Google Developers infoWindow documentation!

Halelujah!